# How to Set Legends different from Titles in PieChart using AChatEngine..?

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, achartengine

I am working on a `PieChart` that needs to display Legends different from Titles displayed on the Top of Chart.But I Could not find any method neither in `CategorySeries` nor in `DefaultRenderer` to do the Same. By default it is Setting the Legend and Title Same for the `PieChart`.

How To Set Category Titles different from Category Legends in `achartengine`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the labels, but you cannot display different labels than the ones in the legend. In order to do that, you would have to checkout the AChartEngine source code and extend it to support the feature you need.

Comment: Thanx Dan for your response...Can you plz Tell Me which Class I need to extend to get the above Feature.

Comment: Take a look at PieChart and RoundChart.

Comment: @AmritpalSingh: Did you manage to change the source code and get it working? It would be really helpful if post the solution. Thanks